# ReSharper automatic search and replace pattern for an event usage

Tags: c#, resharper

Can I make ReSharper find the following issue in my solution

```
if (this.SomeEvent != null)
{
    this.SomeEvent (this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

and replace it with

```
EventHandler handler = this.SomeEvent;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

preferably automated as much as possible?

Comment: i can't recall the reason for this check (ie assigning the event to a temporary variable) - why is it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have R# 5 or later, you can use Structural Search and Replace, to be found at `ReSharper | Find | Search with Pattern...`.

In Search pattern, enter

```
if ($ev$ != null)
{
    $ev$(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

In Replace pattern, enter

```
EventHandler handler = $ev$;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Choose `Add Placeholder | Expression`, and create an expression placeholder named `ev` of type `System.EventHandler`, making sure that `Or derived type` is **checked**.

Click `Replace` and you should be shown all the instances of the search pattern. Click the checkbox at the root of the tree and click Replace to replace them all.

Comment: This search pattern will also find items that are already correct. I would need to have a condition `if $ev$ is not a local variable`.

Comment: It is probably still as good as it gets. I'd have to go through each find manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use [custom paterns](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/08/highlighting-custom-patterns-with-resharper/) for code inspection. In Visual Studio go to Options, Resharper. Under the category "Code Inspection" find "Custom Patterns". There you can add your own code inpsections on top of the many built-in inspections.

The easiest way to get where you want is save the next piece of text into an XML file:

```
<CustomPatterns>
  <Pattern Severity="SUGGESTION" FormatAfterReplace="True" ShortenReferences="True" Language="CSHARP">
    <Comment>Event call is not thread-safe</Comment>
    <ReplaceComment>Convert to thread-safe event call</ReplaceComment>
    <ReplacePattern><![CDATA[var eventHandler = $SomeEvent$;
if (null != eventHandler)
{
    eventHandler($args$);
}
]]></ReplacePattern>
    <SearchPattern><![CDATA[if ($SomeEvent$ != null)
{
   $SomeEvent$ ($args$);
}
]]></SearchPattern>
    <Params>
      <IgnoreBracesInSingleStatementBlocks>False</IgnoreBracesInSingleStatementBlocks>
      <IgnoreParanthesisInExpressions>False</IgnoreParanthesisInExpressions>
      <SmartMatchAssociativeExpressions>False</SmartMatchAssociativeExpressions>
      <TreatReversedBinaryExpressionsEquivalent>Never</TreatReversedBinaryExpressionsEquivalent>
    </Params>
    <Placeholders>
      <ArgumentPlaceholder Name="args" Minimal="-1" Maximal="-1" />
      <ExpressionPlaceholder Name="SomeEvent" ExpressionType="System.EventHandler" ExactType="False" />
    </Placeholders>
  </Pattern>
</CustomPatterns>
```

And use the import function for code inspections. You can see what I did and learn by example.

This will give you a resharper hint in VS and a fix suggestion wherever the pattern occurs. You can use "Find now" to find all occurrences of the search pattern.

One big BUT (sadly). The fixed pattern is recognized as a suspect too. The only way to fix this, as fas as I can see now, is to make the search pattern less generic.

---

**Edit:**

I didn't like my last comment, so I tried to do something about it after all. I changed the XML and now it works. The trick was to reverse the comparison in the replacement code (`if (null != eventHandler)`) and switch off "match similar constructs". I've started to use this code inspection myself, it actually was a great idea!